# Results are differing between trained model and exported model using TFLite model maker

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow-lite

I'm training a multi-class classifier using TF LITE MODEL MAKER examples and the results are differing between the model before and after exporting and the differences are poor from the exported model. Here's the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import os
np.object = object    
np.bool = np.bool_
np.complex = np.complex_
import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import text_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.text_classifier import AverageWordVecSpec
from tflite_model_maker.text_classifier import DataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.export_format import ExportFormat
from tflite_support.task import core
from tflite_support.task import processor
from tflite_support.task import text

try:
    train_data = DataLoader.from_csv(
          filename='label_coded_train.csv',
          text_column='text',
          label_column='label_coded',
          model_spec=spec,
          is_training=True)
    test_data = DataLoader.from_csv(
          filename='lable_coded_test.csv',
          text_column='text',
          label_column='label_coded',
          model_spec=spec,
          is_training=False)
except:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())

model = text_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, epochs=50)
predicts = model.predict_top_k(test_data)
print(predicts)
supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, # enable TensorFlow ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8
]
model.export(export_dir='new2', tflite_filename='model.tflite',quantizatiom_config=None,export_format=ExportFormat.TFLITE,supported_ops= supported_ops,export_metadata_json_file=True)

# Imports
from tflite_support.task import text


classifier = text.NLClassifier.create_from_file('model.tflite')
for idx in range(5):
  sentence = test_df['text'].iloc[idx]
  label = test_df['label_coded'].iloc[idx]
  text_classification_result = classifier.classify(sentence)
  classification_list = text_classification_result.classifications[0].categories
    
  # Sort output by probability descending.
  predict_label = sorted(
      classification_list, key=lambda item: item.score, reverse=True)[0]

  print('truth_label: {} -----> predict_label: {} : {}'.format(label, predict_label.score,predict_label.category_name))
```

I'm getting the predictions of the trained model before exporting like this:

```
[[('380', 0.30081287)],
 [('292', 0.32321274)],
 [('579', 0.45808473)],
 [('185', 0.8556361)],
 [('317', 0.8951897)],
 [('197', 0.10529121)],
```

And the results after exporting the model without any quantization like:

```
predict_label: 0.07742108404636383 : 391
predict_label: 0.0938422754406929 : 542
predict_label: 0.06075349822640419 : 37
predict_label: 0.12074552476406097 : 257
predict_label: 0.04778052121400833 : 316
predict_label: 0.11460260301828384 : 37
```

I have installed the below versions of the packages:

```
tflite-model-maker== 0.4.2
tflite-support == 0.4.3
tensorflow == 2.6.0
numpy==1.19.2
numba==0.53.0
```

Any idea on wha'ts happening and how to approach this?